# Why is a constant declared with the keyword "let" in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

the title says it all...Why is a constant declared with the keyword "let" in Swift?

Probably there's a simple answer to this noob question,  but I couldn't find it on SO.

EDIT: OK, just to make the question clearer. I know that it needs to be initialized with SOME name, but I thought that there maybe is a deeper meaning to let, a source where it originates? Other stuff like "func" seems very logical to me, so I wonder what the deeper meaning of "let" is.

Comment: I like your question, but I believe you won't find the answer here as it is more of a...CS philosophy and Apple's Magic :)

Comment: The `let` designation that makes the creation of a constant explicit. This offers pragmatic advantages over languages with implicit declaration of variables (e.g., languages with implicit declaration of variables make it far too easy to introduce all sort of errors). The rationale for constants vs variables is discussed in the beginning of WWDC 2014 video [Introducing Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=402), in which they discuss how the use of constants is safer, code can be optimized, and makes the programmer's intent more clear.

Comment: In answer to your revised question, `let` has a [rich history in programming languages](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194227/in-what-programming-language-did-let-first-appear)

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Now that was very helpful for a noob like me. Appreciate the history lesson!

Comment: The word let results in variable declarations often being complete English sentences, and let is a complete word in itself, unlike the longer const. Brevity and history are surely the two main reasons.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually in swift there is no concept of constant variable.

A constant is an expression that is resolved at compilation time. For example, in objective C this code:

```
const NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

results in a compilation error, stating that `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant`. The reason is that `NSString` is instantiated at runtime, so it's not a compile time constant.

In swift the closest thing is the immutable variable. The difference may not be evident, but an immutable is not a constant, it's a variable that can be **dynamically** initialized once and cannot be modified thereafter. So, the compile time evaluation is not needed nor required - although it will frequently happen we use immutables as constants:

```
let url = "http://www.myurl.com"

let maxValue = 500

let maxIntervalInSeconds = 5 * 60 *60
```

But immutables can also be initialized with expressions evaluated at runtime:

```
let url = isDebug ? "http://localhost" : "http://www.myservice.com"

let returnCode: Int = {
    switch(errorCode) {
    case 0: return 0
    default: return 1
    }
}()
```

The latter example is interesting: using a closure, immediately executed, to initialize an immutable variable (differently from `var`, immutables don't support deferred initialization, so that's the only way to initialize using a multi line expression)

Comment: Thanks Antonio. But why is it initialized with "let" and and not with "foo" or "cheesecake"? sorry, but I think I missed the part answering my initial question.

Comment: It has to be something, right? "let" is often used in this way in mathematics: let x = 5, let y = x * 2, etc.

Comment: I think "let" was originally used in BASIC, at the beginning of times...

Comment: @theremin I think they didn't choose `const` because it's not a constant. As to why they chose `let`... you won't find an answer here - you should ask the creator :)

Comment: Thanks, Antonio! I thought there's a deeper meaning that everybody else knows except me.

Comment: To be honest I wondered myself during my first swift days... `let` reminds me of variable declaration in old BASIC, so at beginning it was confusing. But that lasted a couple days only, soon I got used to that name.

Comment: Sounds like a "final" variable in Java

Comment: It is probably silly and not relevant here but I always think "let" as "let it be"

Comment: Apple itself calls them constants in their documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID311